# 2-bit charge redistribution DAC output

Tags: dac

So here is the circuit:

[image]

And here is the output:

[image]

I presume answer c) is the output when there's a transition from phase 1 to phase 2. What about the transition from phase 2 to phase 1?

Vout will be equal to 0 because of the non inverting input being a virtual ground, why is this case ignored? 0 is being sampled, that makes non sense in a dac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What about the transition from phase 2 to phase 1?
Vout will be equal to 0 because of the non inverting input being a virtual ground, why is this case ignored? 0 is being sampled, that makes non sense in a dac*.

You are correct about returning to zero during this phase.
This might seem like non-sense, but as you progress on sampled data systems, you will find it's quite common to have return to zero data format like this.

As an example, in a pipeline ADC, the multiplying DAC is often return to zero, and the system alternates on half phases of the sample clock. So only half the DAC output is necessary each half cycle. You can force the output to be held by adding a switch at the output.